# Angular check string pattern on `Template`

Tags: angular, string, angular-ng-if

I am trying to add a condition to my `*ngIf` where it will display only if the string ends with `.txt` in my template.

I've tried this but it's not working:

```html
<div *ngIf="myfilename.endsWith('.txt')">...</div>
```

I know the above does not work, so my question is:

**How can I do this so I only display `.txt` filenames?**

Comment: You can handle in component and set the flag based on your requirement and check that flag in template with ngif

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Can you post your data to see if myfilename is in the correct format? Because your code looks good and I think it should work.

Comment: instead of myfilename.endsWith, try myfilename.split('.') and compare with .txt with last index, something like this myfilename.split('.')[((myfilename.split('.')).length)-1]
If the myfilename is extracting the right filename contains only one 'dot' with .txt extension

Comment: hmmm interesting ... myfilename would be just filename.txt that's it

Comment: then my above comment should work if .endWith doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to check it in your `component.ts` for example like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent impelemnts OnInit  {
  myfilename: string;
  isTxt: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isTxt = this.myfilename.endsWith(".txt")
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="isTxt">...</div>
```